Flutter: Popup Resize when keboard apears issue in fluttrer
I'm facing an issue with popups in my Flutter app. When the keyboard appears, the popup resizes and becomes difficult to interact with.
**
Screenshots:**

image without apearnce of keyboard
when keyboard apears

As you can see in the screenshots, when the keyboard is not visible, the popup displays correctly. However, once the keyboard appears, the popup resizes, and it's difficult to see or scroll through the content.
**
What I have tried:**
I am using the showDialog function to display the popup inside a Future function. However, I'm not sure how to prevent the popup from resizing when the keyboard appears. Ideally, I want the popup to remain the same size and for the text field I click on to be focused without affecting the popup's layout.
What do I need help with?

How can I prevent the popup from resizing when the keyboard appears?
Is there a way to ensure that when I click on a text field, it focuses correctly without altering      the popup layout?
Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Bellow is the Code.
@override
  Future<Customer?> showAddNewCustomer(String? cust) async {
    var formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    TextEditingController firstNameController = TextEditingController(text: '');
    TextEditingController lastNameController = TextEditingController(text: '');
    TextEditingController phoneController = TextEditingController(text: '');
    TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController(text: '');
    TextEditingController zipController = TextEditingController(text: '');
    TextEditingController cityController = TextEditingController(text: '');
    TextEditingController stateController = TextEditingController(text: '');
    String? stateAbr;
    if (cust != null && cust.isNotEmpty) {
      if (cust.length == 10 && StringExtension.isNumeric(cust)) {
        phoneController.text = StringExtension.formatPhone(cust)!;
      } else {
        firstNameController.text = cust;
      }
    }
    var isLoader = EasyLoading.isShow ? true : false;
    if (isLoader) {
      await EasyLoading.dismiss();
    }
    var res = await showDialog<Customer?>(
        barrierDismissible: false,
        context: __globalService.navigatorKey.currentContext!,
        builder: (_) => PopScope(
              canPop: false,
              child: Dialog(
                  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
                  child: Builder(builder: (context) {
                    // Get available height and width of the build area of this widget. Make a choice depending on the size.
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: 600,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 20),
                              child: Text(
                                AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                                    .translate('addNewCustomer'),
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Flexible(
                              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                child: Container(
                                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                                      child: Form(
                                          key: formKey,
                                          child: Column(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                                  CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                              children: [
                                                Row(
                                                  children: [
                                                    Expanded(
                                                        child: DefaultTextInput(
                                                      labelText:
                                                          AppLocalizations.of(
                                                                  context)!
                                                              .translate(
                                                                  'firstName'),
                                                      hintText: AppLocalizations
                                                              .of(context)!
                                                          .translate(
                                                              'firstName...'),
                                                      controller:
                                                          firstNameController,
                                                      validator: (value) {
                                                        if (value == null ||
                                                            value.isEmpty) {
                                                          return AppLocalizations
                                                                  .of(context)!
                                                              .translate(
                                                                  'enterFirstName');
                                                        }
                                                        return null;
                                                      },
                                                    )),
                                                    const SizedBox(
                                                      width: 10,
                                                    ),
                                                    Expanded(
                                                        child: DefaultTextInput(
                                                      labelText:
                                                          AppLocalizations.of(
                                                                  context)!
                                                              .translate(
                                                                  'lastName'),
                                                      hintText: AppLocalizations
                                                              .of(context)!
                                                          .translate(
                                                              'lastName...'),
                                                      controller:
                                                          lastNameController,
                                                      validator: (value) {
                                                        if (value == null ||
                                                            value.isEmpty) {
                                                          return AppLocalizations
                                                                  .of(context)!
                                                              .translate(
                                                                  'enterLastName');
                                                        }
                                                        return null;
                                                      },
                                                    )),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                                const SizedBox(
                                                  height: 25,
                                                ),
                                                DefaultTextInput(
                                                  formatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                                                    FilteringTextInputFormatter
                                                        .allow(RegExp("[0-9]")),
                                                    MaskTextInputFormatter(
                                                        mask: "(###) ###-####")
                                                  ],
                                                  labelText: AppLocalizations
                                                          .of(context)!
                                                      .translate(
                                                          'phoneForLoyalty'),
                                                  hintText: AppLocalizations.of(
                                                          context)!
                                                      .translate('phone...'),
                                                  controller: phoneController,
                                                  validator: (value) {
                                                    if (value != null &&
                                                        value.isNotEmpty &&
                                                        value.length != 14) {
                                                      return AppLocalizations
                                                              .of(context)!
                                                          .translate(
                                                              'validPhone');
                                                    }
                                                    return null;
                                                  },
                                                ),
                                                const SizedBox(
                                                  height: 25,
                                                ),
                                                DefaultTextInput(
                                                  formatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                                                    FilteringTextInputFormatter
                                                        .allow(RegExp(
                                                            "[0-9@a-zA-Z.]")),
                                                  ],
                                                  labelText:
                                                      AppLocalizations.of(
                                                              context)!
                                                          .translate('email'),
                                                  hintText: AppLocalizations.of(
                                                          context)!
                                                      .translate('email...'),
                                                  controller: emailController,
                                                  validator: (value) {
                                                    if (value != null &&
                                                        value.isNotEmpty &&
                                                        !isValidEmail(value)) {
                                                      return AppLocalizations
                                                              .of(context)!
                                                          .translate(
                                                              'validEmail');
                                                    }
                                                    return null;
                                                  },
                                                ),
                                                const SizedBox(height: 25),
                                                Focus(
                                                  child: DefaultTextInput(
                                                    formatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                                                      FilteringTextInputFormatter
                                                          .allow(
                                                              RegExp("[0-9]")),
                                                      MaskTextInputFormatter(
                                                          mask: "#####")
                                                    ],
                                                    labelText:
                                                        AppLocalizations.of(
                                                                context)!
                                                            .translate('zip'),
                                                    hintText: AppLocalizations
                                                            .of(context)!
                                                        .translate('zip...'),
                                                    controller: zipController,
                                                    validator: (value) {
                                                      if (value != null &&
                                                          value.isNotEmpty) {
                                                        if (value.length != 5) {
                                                          return AppLocalizations
                                                                  .of(context)!
                                                              .translate(
                                                                  'validZip');
                                                        }
                                                      }
                                                      return null;
                                                    },
                                                  ),
                                                  onFocusChange: (value) async {
                                                    if (!value) {
                                                      if (zipController
                                                              .text.length ==
                                                          5) {
                                                        await EasyLoading.show(
                                                            status:
                                                                'loading...');
                                                        var zipInfo =
                                                            await _apiService
                                                                .getZipInfo(int.parse(
                                                                    zipController
                                                                        .text));
                                                        if (zipInfo.errorCode ==
                                                            "PA0004") {
                                                          ZipInfo zip = zipInfo
                                                              .data as ZipInfo;
                                                          cityController.text =
                                                              zip.city ?? "";
                                                          stateController.text =
                                                              zip.stateFullname ??
                                                                  "";
                                                        }
                                                        await EasyLoading
                                                            .dismiss();
                                                      }
                                                    }
                                                  },
                                                ),
                                                const SizedBox(height: 25),
                                                DefaultTextInput(
                                                  labelText:
                                                      AppLocalizations.of(
                                                              context)!
                                                          .translate('city'),
                                                  hintText: AppLocalizations.of(
                                                          context)!
                                                      .translate('city...'),
                                                  controller: cityController,
                                                ),
                                                const SizedBox(height: 25),
                                                DefaultTextInput(
                                                    readOnly: true,
                                                    isDropDown: true,
                                                    labelText:
                                                        AppLocalizations.of(
                                                                context)!
                                                            .translate('state'),
                                                    hintText: AppLocalizations
                                                            .of(context)!
                                                        .translate('state...'),
                                                    controller: stateController,
                                                    onTap: () async {
                                                      var statesRes =
                                                          await _apiService
                                                              .getUSStates();
                                                      var states = statesRes
                                                          ?.map((state) =>
                                                              state.name)
                                                          .toList();
                                                      var res = await showSelect(
                                                          Message(
                                                              description:
                                                                  "Please Select an Option",
                                                              items: states));
                                                      if (res != -1) {
                                                        stateController.text =
                                                            statesRes![res]
                                                                .name!;
                                                        stateAbr =
                                                            statesRes[res]
                                                                .abbreviation!;
                                                      }
                                                    }),
                                              ]))),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
                              child: Row(children: [
                                const Expanded(child: Text('')),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 40,
                                  child: ElevatedButton(
                                    style: ButtonStyle(
                                        shape: WidgetStateProperty.all<
                                                RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                            RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(5))),
                                        elevation: WidgetStateProperty.all(0)),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.of(context).pop(null);
                                    },
                                    child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                                        .translate('close')), // <-- Text
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  width: 10,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 40,
                                  child: ElevatedButton(
                                    style: ButtonStyle(
                                      shape: WidgetStateProperty.all<
                                              RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                          RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                      )),
                                      elevation: WidgetStateProperty.all(0),
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                      if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                        await EasyLoading.show(
                                            status: 'loading...');
                                        try {
                                          var response = await _apiService
                                              .addCustomer(Customer(
                                                  firstName:
                                                      firstNameController.text,
                                                  lastName:
                                                      lastNameController.text,
                                                  phone: StringExtension
                                                      .unformatPhone(
                                                          phoneController.text),
                                                  email: emailController.text,
                                                  postalCode:
                                                      zipController.text,
                                                  city: cityController.text,
                                                  isLoyal: true,
                                                  username: StringExtension
                                                      .unformatPhone(
                                                          phoneController.text),
                                                  role: ["Customer"],
                                                  rewardPoints: 0,
                                                  state: stateAbr ??
                                                      stateController.text));
                                          if (response.errorCode == "PA0004") {
                                            if (context.mounted) {
                                              Navigator.of(context).pop(
                                                  response.data as Customer);
                                            }
                                          } else {
                                            await _errorReportingService
                                                .showError(response);
                                          }
                                        } catch (e) {
                                          debugPrint(e.toString());
                                        } finally {
                                          await EasyLoading.dismiss();
                                        }
                                      }
                                    },
                                    child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                                        .translate('save')), // <-- Text
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ]),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  })),
            ));
    if (isLoader) {
      await EasyLoading.show(status: 'loading...');
    }
    return res;
  }


Well there is no way to make the thing that you are trying to do in flutter because this is aint resizing, its getting hight decreased to leave some space for the keyboard,
You can convert your dialog to a BottomSheet and you already have a lot of data in you dialog so if you put them in a BottomSheet it will be better and you will not face this problem :)

is there any way if we can do is when keyboard appears it should appear on top of the popup just like an overlay i think, so it appearance of keyboard doesnt affect its height and even when i focus an entry of most bottom one from popup it should focused and easily ba able to view when keyboard appear

This is a known bug: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7032
